# Intercepting/debugging wrapper over a program with bidirectional command/response interface

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have a command-line program, the `target`, that implements a command/response interface over stdio (for other programs, not for humans).

Specifically:

- the consumer of this program starts it up
- reads 1 or more lines from its stdout (its "greeting")
- sends 1 or more lines to its stdin (the "command")
- reads 1 or more lines from its stdout (the "response")
- ...

This happens in a loop until the `target` terminates, which presumably happens on receipt of a "quit" command of some sort.

The delays between the commands and the responses may be arbitrary. I believe that the `target` may also initiate some commands of its own (that the consumer has to respond to), but I'm not sure.

---

How do I wrap this program in some way to be able to log (or, better yet, log and potentially modify) all commands and responses?

Comment: not quite sure, are you looking for the `chat` program?

Comment: @MarcusMüller correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `chat` needs me to provide a script that consists of "expect"+"send" pairs. I, on the other hand, need to write a logging proxy that can work without knowledge of the protocol.

Comment: yes, read `man chat` regarding the `v` option.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do not have a script that I can provide to `chat`.

Comment: kinda `tee stdin.log | program | tee stdout.log` but you can't be sure of the order / relation between stdin stdout unless its somehow fixed (always just 1 line or otherwise structured/delimited data). Pipe buffering might also be an issue. In the end comes down to writing a program that does much the same thing as the consumer...

Comment: yeah, I mean, the most logical thing here is to actually add that logging to *your* program, because only you know how data is terminated, and separate streams are asynchronous, so the log will not be very useful if you just log things as they come in, when bytes fly in both direction at the same time.

Comment: You might also want to either use, or inspect the code of the [tag:expect] utility.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Neither is my program. I want to reverse-engineer the protocol in use.

Comment: *"I want to reverse-engineer the protocol in use"*. I recommend you include that as the first line of your question. Readers will need more details about what technologies you wish to support.

Comment: For logging io you might look at `script -c` ([man](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)), or `socat -v` or `-x` to log 2-way data over whatever connection mechanism you have.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to start with a few assumptions. Especially, that your one program doesn't send be commands before your target program is done sending the reply to the previous command. Otherwise, logging things simultaneously will look pretty garbled. For this assumption to work, you need to make sure your programs that you insert between sink and source do not use buffering.

Two solutions:

## 1. Double tee with shell FDs

In a shell script, you can disable buffering (that's very important in this use case), and then redirect the stdout of your client program to `tee -a logfile`, which then simultaneously logs into a file; you connect `tee`'s stdout to to a temporary FD.

just like for that, you'd use your shell's constructs to create a file descriptor that you use as stdin of your client program, and another file descriptor for the stdout of your `target` program. Then you finally pipe the "reply" direction, formed by these two for descriptors, through another `tee -a logfile`.

Finally, you use the first `tee`s stdout stream as input to your `target`, and your second `tee`'s stdin stream as output.

## 2. Debug your processes

Using various methods, you can hook into what your target or client processes read and write and log that.

With an appropriate LD_PRELOAD you could intercept the libc `read` and `write` calls that interact with the programs' stdin and stdout, and log these. Problem: not everything uses the libc.

Alternatively, and that's what is recommended: bpftools comes with snooping examples that catch the underlying syscalls - there's no way around that. Log what your filter program shows!